# tensorflow - Create input tensor from a gstreamer buffer

Tags: c++, tensorflow, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I am currently writing a Gstreamer1.0 plugin that would intercept a frame, use tensorflow to perform some task, write data on the frame and inject it back in.

I am doing this in C/C++ and i am currently facing an issue when data must flow between Gstreamer and Tensorflow.

I have a frame in a GstBuffer object from which i have to extract data and construct an input Tensor.
The format is always the same, a UINT8 RGB matrix [width,height,3]

```
/* extract raw data from gstreamer buffer */
gpointer bytes;
gst_buffer_extract_dup(outbuf, 0, size, &bytes, &copied);
```

With bytes pointer i now have to construct :

```
Tensor input(tensorflow::DT_UINT8, tensorflow::TensorShape(cwidth, cheight, 3));
```

I have no idea how i am supposed to do that.
I could not find any information or example on how i can work with a gpointer and on tensorflow i could only really find examples using a file as the source which is not my case at all.

Any leads or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way but it does only work when your buffer is a RGB, 3 channels frame buffer.

```
Tensor ConvertRGBBufferToInputTensor(gpointer buffer, gint cwidth, gint cheight, gint channel) {

    Tensor input_tensor(tensorflow::DT_UINT8, tensorflow::TensorShape({1, cwidth, cheight, channel}));
    auto input_tensor_mapped = input_tensor.tensor<uint8_t, 4>();

    uint8_t * uintdata = (uint8_t*)buffer;

    for (int y = 0; y < cheight; ++y) {
        const uint8_t* source_row = uintdata + (y * cwidth * channel);
        for (int x = 0; x < cwidth; ++x) {
            const uint8_t* source_pixel = source_row + (x * channel);
            for (int c = 0; c < channel; ++c) {
                const uint8_t* source_value = source_pixel + c;
                input_tensor_mapped(0, y, x, c) = *source_value;
            }
        }
    }

    return input_tensor;
}
```

And to use it from gstreamer when you have a GstBuffer

```
/* extract raw data from the buffer and convert it to an input tensor */
gst_buffer_extract_dup(outbuf, 0, size, &bytes, &copied);
GST_INFO("Extracted %" G_GSIZE_FORMAT " from buffer" , copied);
Tensor input_tensor = ConvertRGBBufferToInputTensor(bytes, cwidth, cheight);
g_free(bytes);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is already implemented and deployed for gstreamer application developers: https://github.com/nnsuite/nnstreamer

You can write GStreamer pipelines such as,

```
camsrc ! videoconvert ! videorate ! videoscale ! video/x-raw, whatever-format-you-need ! tensor_converter ! tensor_filter framework=tensorflow model=your-own-model-file.pb ! ....
```

If what you need is transpose

```
camsrc ! videoconvert ! videorate ! videoscale ! video/x-raw, whatever-format-you-need ! tensor_converter ! tensor_transform mode=transpose option=1:2:0:3 ! tensor_filter framework=tensorflow model=your-own-model-file.pb ! ....
```

If you want to import the results into your application, you can add app_sink or tensor_sink and get the resulting tensors there.